# Drop columns with no content in any of the rows and drop corresponding columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop columns that have no content in **any** of the rows and drop other columns that starts with the same name.

In this example, *Line of Business > Organization* should be dropped since there are only blanks in all the rows. And since this column is dropped, all other columns starting with *"Line of business >"* should also be dropped from the pandas data frame. The complete data frame follows the same structure of *[some text] > [Organization/Department/Employees]*.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Process name': {0: 'Ad campaign', 1: 'Payroll', 2: ''},
                   'Line of business > Organization': {0: "", 1: "", 2:''},
                   'Line of business > Department': {0: "Social media", 1: "People", 2:''},
                   'Line of business > Employees': {0: "Linda, Tom", 1: "Manuel, Olaf", 2:''}})
```

Result:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'Process name': {0: 'Ad campaign', 1: 'Payroll', 2: ''}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand the case correctly, but I think you could try this:

First, replace the emtpy "" values with NaNs:

```
data.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Then, identify the empty cols like this:

```
empty_cols = [col for col in data.columns if data[col].isnull().all()]
```

Next, identify the columns to be deleted. (this assumes that the '>' is the separator of the text relevant to identify this).

```
delete_cols= [col for col in data.columns for empty_col in empty_cols if col.split('>')[0] == empty_col.split('>')[0]]
```

At last, drop the columns you don't need and drop null values from the columns remaining:

```
data = data.drop(delete_cols, axis=1).dropna()
```

Comment: thanks! the `dropna()` part in `data.drop(delete_cols, axis=1).dropna()` wipes my entire df, but running `df.replace` instead works well